# Is 'std::allocator<T>::construct' thread-safe, when constructing different elements?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Does the c++ standard guarantees that constructing different elements with std::allocator is thread-safe? For example:

```
// main thread
std::allocator<T> alloc;
auto *p = alloc.allocate(2);

// thread1
alloc.construct(p);

// thread2
alloc.construct(p + 1)
```

Also, is std::allocator::destroy thread-safe for different elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 20.7.9.1 allocator members [allocator.members]
>
> 1 Except for the destructor, member functions of the default allocator shall not introduce data races (1.10)
> as a result of concurrent calls to those member functions from different threads. Calls to these functions
> that allocate or deallocate a particular unit of storage shall occur in a single total order, and each such
> deallocation call shall happen before the next allocation (if any) in this order.

So yes, concurrent calls to `construct` and `destroy` on `std::allocator<T>` are guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's helpful